# i just started learning javascript and i'm trying to make a calculator website but can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, html, web

I wrote a code composed of HTML, CSS, and javascript and it's supposed to be a calculator in a website. however, since i'm not very experienced with coding in javascript, i ran into some problems. for now i've only coded the part for the number input (not for operations and deleting) and when i click on any number, nothing comes up in the display box. can anyone help me please?

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousoperandtextelement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    this.operation = undefined
  }

  delete() {

  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    this.currentOperand = number
  }

  chooseoperation(operation) {

  }

  compute() {

  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand
  }
}

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const allcleaButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="calculator-grid">
  <div class="output">
    <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
    <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
  </div>
  <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
  <button data-delete>DEL</button>
  <button data-operation>÷</button>
  <button data-number>1</button>
  <button data-number>2</button>
  <button data-number>3</button>
  <button data-operation>*</button>
  <button data-number>4</button>
  <button data-number>5</button>
  <button data-number>6</button>
  <button data-operation>+</button>
  <button data-number>7</button>
  <button data-number>8</button>
  <button data-number>9</button>
  <button data-operation>-</button>
  <button data-number>.</button>
  <button data-number>0</button>
  <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appendNumber` doesn't append. It overwrites. `<input type="text">` doesn't have `innerText`. It has a `value`:

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperand = ''
  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    this.currentOperand += number   
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.value = this.currentOperand
  }
}

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')

const calculator = new Calculator(currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})
```

```html
<button data-number>1</button>
<input type="text" data-current-operand>
```